# Why exit status always coming 0. What will be the solution

Tags: shell

Below code is the part of my shell script.
But I am not able to understand why exit status(sshStatus) always coming 0?
I want ssh output as well as exit status.
Please help me to find the solution.

```
local output="$(ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=10 \
               -o BatchMode=yes \
               -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
               -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
               $user@$host "$command" 2>&1)"
        local sshStatus=$?
```

command can be :

```
command="[ ! -d /home/upendra/dfs ]" 
command="cat /home/upendra/a.txt"
command="sh /home/upendra/dfs/bin/start-datanode.sh"
```

Whenever i'm calling command like below directly on shell prompt:

```
ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=10 \
               -o BatchMode=yes \
               -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
               -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
               upendra@172.20.20.2 "[ ! -d /home/upendra/dfs ]" 2>&1
```

Then exit status(echo $?) is coming 1. This is correct because this directory not exists on host.

Comment: Thanks you all.
I got solution on this page :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code
it is due to "local output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution on this page :[bash shell - ssh remote script capture output and exit code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66581/bash-shell-ssh-remote-script-capture-output-and-exit-code) it is due to "local output". –  Upendra

Answer (score 0):

Every command returns an exit status (sometimes referred to as a return status or exit code). A successful command returns a **0**, while an unsuccessful command returns a **non-zero** value that usually can be interpreted as an error code. Well-behaved UNIX commands, programs, and utilities return a **0** *exit code upon successful completion*, though there are some exceptions.

Likewise, functions within a script and the script itself return an exit status. The last command executed in the function or script determines the exit status. Within a script, an exit **nnn** command may be used to deliver an **nnn** exit status to the shell (**nnn** must be an *integer in the 0 - 255 range*).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello 
echo $?    # Exit status 0 returned because command executed successfully.

lskdf      # Unrecognized command. echo $?    # Non-zero exit status
returned -- command failed to execute.

echo

exit 113   # Will return 113 to shell.
           # To verify this, type "echo $?" after script terminates.
```

*Your code return exit code **0** which means your shell script execute successfully.*

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting exot status as `0` as your `command` is excecuted successfully

The exit status you obtain from the local machine is the exit status of the last command in ssh session

for example

```
$ ssh localhost
$ exit 5
$ echo $?  #on local system
5
```

Consider a case without any command

```
$ ssh localhost
$ ls
#will list commands and exit succussfully
ctrl+d
$ echo $?  #on local system
0
```

Here the exit status of `ls` command is `0` which is printed.

Comment: But I'm getting exit status 0 if command="[ ! -d /home/upendra/dfs ]". Where this directory already exists on server. Here exit status should be 1.

Comment: am not sure. works fine on my system.  out of curiousity, why you use so many quoting.